# Flutter: Change Color of Circular Progress Indicator on a certain value

Tags: flutter, colors, flutter-circularprogressindicator

is it possible to change to valueColor of a CircularProgressIndicator when a certain value is being reached.

For Example: 
Green, if value < 30 
Orange, if value < 60 
Red, if value > 60

Thanks for the help! :)

```
CircularProgressIndicator(
                            strokeWidth: 6,
                            value: amountSpent / budget,
                            backgroundColor: UiColors.backgroundColor,
                            valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
                                UiColors.categoryColors[1]),
                          ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a function that will calculate the adequate color for your CircularProgressIndicator.

I create you a [DartPad where you can preview the working widget.](https://dartpad.dev/accf9c466d6de6e76d0ded9879503eee?null_safety=true)

```
CircularProgressIndicator(
    strokeWidth: 6,
    value: amountSpent / budget,
    backgroundColor: calculateBackgroundColor(value: amountSpent / budget)
    valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(UiColors.categoryColors[1]),
),

// Define a function to calculate the adequate color:
Color calculateBackgroundColor({required double value}) {
    if (value > 0.60) {
        return Colors.red;
    } else if (value > 0.30) {
        return Colors.orange;
    } else {
        return Colors.green;
    }
}
```